# Pgpass not working in unixODBC/pyodbc

Tags: python, postgresql, pyodbc, unixodbc

So I can't seem to get PostgreSQL's ".pgpass" functionality working using unixODBC/pyodbc in Python.

I have a working ~/.pgpass file, as confirmed by the command-line tool psql, and I have a working odbc.ini entry as confirmed by my Python script.  The problem here is that I want the script to pick up the password via the ~/.pgpass file as I don't want to have to specify the password in either the DSN entry nor the odbc.ini entry (either of which works).

I've tried setting the local and host entries in pg_hba.conf to various values including md5, password, ident, peer, and trust.  Trust of course works, but that puts security at a level I'm not comfortable with since it's not actually doing any authentication.

Has anyone gotten this to work?  Here's some relevant entries:

pg_hba.conf

```
local   all             all                                     md5
host    all             all             127.0.0.1/32            md5
host    all             all             ::1/128                 md5
host    all             all             0.0.0.0/0               md5
host    all             all             ::/0                    md5
```

odbc.ini

```
[MyEntry]
Driver                  = PostgreSQL
Server                  = myServer
Port                    = 5432
Database                = myDB
Username                = myUser
Trace                   = Yes
```

.pgpass

```
myServer:5432:*:myUser:myPassword
```

Comment: Any reason why you're not using psycopg2 instead?

Comment: Because I'm also connecting to MSSQL and MySQL databases.  Using pyodbc gives me a single interface to any database I want to connect to.

Comment: That's absolutely fair. I also connect to all three, but use the separate drivers (psycopg2, pyodbc, mysql-connector-python) for performance and simplicity. It does get slightly confusing as they have different parameter syntaxes and such.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

.pgpass file used by libpq. You can not use it from odbc.